# mouse click in scrollbar changes selection

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ubuntu-10.04, emacs23

When I mouse click on the emacs scrollbar, emacs sets the mark at the mouse-down location (the end of that line, since the mouse is actually in the scrollbar) before the scroll and sets point at the mouse-up location after the scroll. This makes a new active selection. Is there a way to make scrollbar clicking like keyboard scrolling or mouse-wheel scrolling (which does NOT mess with mark, nor change whether or not a selection is active)?

I have emacs 23.1+1-4ubuntu7.2 (the current version for my Xubuntu 10.04 LTS installation).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this bug:
http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=9541

If not, consider filing a bug for this, using `M-x report-emacs-bug'.